# Keeping a jQuery popup inside the browser viewport

Tags: jquery

I'm having some difficulty with pop up images in JQuery.

Here's a link to the working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/aETbw/27/

If you hover over the little camera icon a photo pops up.

I'd like the pop up image to stay within the viewport, where the viewport is large enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "viewport" (I don't see that word in the jsfiddle)?  Also, could you explain "where the viewport is large enough" further?

Comment: Sorry- I mean the browser window. So if the x and y values that the code generates move the image beyond the edge of what's visible, it moves the image up if the image would have extended beyond the bottom of the browser window, left if it would have extended beyond the right edge and so on.

Comment: When I say "where the viewport is large enough", I mean when the viewport is smaller than the photo itself, in which case some overspill will be unavoidable. But say the photo is 400px by 400px and it would appear 200px from the right edge of the browser window, it would shuffle 200px to the left, so that the whole image was visible. Unless the browser window was only 300px, in which case 100px of the image wouldn't be visible anyway.

Comment: Apologies for my initial explanation! And thanks for taking a look : )

Comment: +1 for the jsfiddle. Made the solution quite a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check to make sure the image popup and it's offset isn't wider than the content area. If it is then position the image popup right vs left. You can't get the true width of the image popup until after the actual image is loaded. Once it is loaded then run your width check.

```
$('#imgPop').css({'left':x+'px','top':y+'px'}).show();
$('#imgPop img').load(function(){
    if($('#imgPop img').width() + x > $('#mainContent').width())
        $('#imgPop').css({'left':'','right':'0px'});
});
```

See the new fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/UBpep/

**UPDATE**

I updated my answer to meet the new requests in the comments. The fiddle link above is updated as well.

```
var hide_popup_timeout = setTimeout(function(){},0);
function hide_popup(){
    clearTimeout(hide_popup_timeout);
    hide_popup_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#imgPop').hide();
        $('#imgPop img').attr('src','');
    },500);
}

$('#article_list img').hover(function(event) {

    clearTimeout(hide_popup_timeout);

    var x = 30;//$(this).offset().left + 30;
    var y = 50;//$(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    $('#imgPop').css({'left':x+'px','top':y+'px'});
    $('#imgPop img').attr('src', $(this).attr('rel'));
    $('#imgPop img').load(function(){
        if($('#imgPop img').width() + x > 
           $('#article_list').width())
            $('#imgPop').css({'left':'','right':'0px'});
    });
    $('#imgPop').show();

},function(){
    hide_popup();         
});

$('#imgPop').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(hide_popup_timeout );
},function(){
    hide_popup();
});​
```

Comment: I also cleaned up some of your jQuery in the fiddle example.

Comment: Hi @iambriansreed. That looks like what I'm after! There are only a couple of things I'm still struggling with: I'd like it to do the same thing if it hits the bottom or top of the browser window. I've updated the markup slightly and removed comments- I couldn't read it properly : ) [link to new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBpep/5/)

Comment: The other thing is, I think I'll need to edit the default coordinates so that they're x 30px and y 50px. If I do this, the image overlaps the pointer and disappears as, I'm guessing, it's not hovering over the little camera image any longer. Is there any way to force the image to stay displayed if the pointer is hovering over it too?

Comment: Oops- I forgot to add the <li> tags inside the <ul>! Here's the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UBpep/7/

Comment: Manually setting the popup to open at 30x50 there is no need to make sure it doesn't run off the page. At this point I have answered your original question and several more. :)

Comment: Voted up. The only issue is with the bottom of the browser window. The image still extends below it… Using the bottom of a specified parent element would work for the images once you hit the bottom of the page, but for those half way down it wouldn't. Here's the edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UBpep/32/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8831/discussion-between-martin-and-iambriansreed)